# List of things what JavaScript is capable of

Tags: javascript

I can easily find what Flash or Silverlight capable of, but it's really hard to find what JavaScript can do.

**Is there someone who can give me a list of major JavaScript features?**

(something like: working with file systems, Web cam support, JSON parsing, socket support, and so on)

---

**Update**

If you say that it depends on platform, then do this: Platform - list of features, Platform - list of features...

The problem is that no one has ever came up with a complete list of features of all the Javascript platforms.

---

**Update**

Javascript - is a language.. but in my point of view it's also a client side technology (it was developed as a plugin for browser, same as Flash, same as Silverlight)

Silverlight can work in browser (and i can find list of feature for that 'mode') and OOB (out of browser, and i can also find list of features for that 'mode'), but i can't find list of features for JavaScript... is i the only one who interested in this? :)

Comment: I don't think the question is well-posed. Javascript can do anything, as it is Turing complete (in particular any turing complete language can do JSON parsing), but access to external resources (such as sockets or a webcam) is limited to the API which are available on a certain environment. So it depends on the environment: the answer will be different for a browser, node.js or rhino. If you mean Javascript inside a browser: not much. The basic available API are the DOM and BOM, although with HTML5 there will be some new features fro storage and sockets.

Comment: @Andrea: Could have been an answer.

Comment: @Andrea i think your comment is a suitable answer

Comment: Since people advised this, I have posted my comment as an answer.

Comment: @Ai_boy please write proper English in your posts.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper Thx a lot.. you opened my eyes.. i would never ever write on "unproper English" :)

Answer (score 9):

I don't think the question is well-posed. Javascript can do anything, as it is Turing complete (in particular any turing complete language can do JSON parsing), but access to external resources (such as sockets or a webcam) is limited to the API which are available on a certain environment.

So it depends on the environment: the answer will be different for a browser, node.js or rhino. If you mean Javascript inside a browser: not much. The basic available API are the DOM and BOM, although with HTML5 there will be some new features for storage and sockets.

**EDIT** I have read your update, and I think it is unreasonable to ask for the features of every existing environment. Still, it seems to me you are mostly interested in the features of client-side Javascript - i.e. in the browser. Until recently, one was tied with the following two APIs:

- DOM: allows to traverse and modify the Document Object Model, that is, operates on the content of the current page. It can add `div` or other elements, change elements style and so on.
- BOM: the Browser object model. It allows you to operate on browser features which are not tied to the current document, for instance resize the current window. In particular this includes the
- XMLHttpRequest: allows you to make an HTTP request in the background, it is at the base of all the AJAX-driven application. For security reasons, there are domain restriction on where you can send this request: these are known as the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

For obvious security reasons there was (and still there is not) a way to operate on local documents. With the advent of HTML5 there are a number of new API, some of which are still under heavy development. In general you cannot rely on those API on older browers.

[This presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/remy.sharp/html5-js-apis) sums up the new goodies which will be available once all clients support HTML5.

Besides the DOM and BOM API you can also make use of **Web API's**. Note that XMLHttpRequest is a Web API. You can see the complete list at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API.

Comment: about your 'edit', i know that askin about all platforms is too much, but you could list at least some major platforms, or write down platform that you knew. **tnx for descriprion, but it's too shallow**

Comment: Did you have a look to the linked presentation? There is no need to repeat what is already there.

Comment: If you want to look for other platforms, search Google for V8, rhino, node.js, XULrunner. Since - for instance - V8 can be embedded in C++ applications and XULrunner can be expanded in C as well, there is no limit about what you can do with it. Your question amounts to what you can do with C/C++.

Comment: what i mean is.. i know that javascript can parse a json.. ok.. can it parse xml, pdf, docx?

Comment: and btw, presintation is two years old..

Comment: On the other hand, it would be impossible for me to list what is possible to do in these environments out of the box. A quick glance at, say, the XPCOM documentation (the XPCOM API is available in XULrunner) will show that there is **a lot** of things you can do. The only reason why you can find a detailed features list for Silverlight or Flash is that those platforms are developed by a single vendor. On the other hand, Javascript is just a language, and it is implemented in plenty of platforms.

Comment: It still seems that your ideas are not clear. What do you mean 'can it parse XML'? Of course it can, every language can. If you ask whether there exists a ready-made library to parse XML in Javascript, it turns out yes - indeed XMLHttpRequest will do the trick on browsers. Is there a library in Javascript to work with PDF files? As far as I know the answer is negative, but this does not mean one could not write such a library.

Comment: Or even take an existing C library, add some glue to wrap it sa an XPCOM object and have that library available on the XULrunner platform.

Comment: tnx a lot.. this is what i want to hear, can i 'teoreticly' write pdf, doc, docx, avi, wav, parsers?

Comment: Yes - but mind: depending on the environment Javascript may have no access to the files in the first place. Moreover, in order to write a library which interacts with, say, PDF files you have to either know the PDF specification or leverage an existing library for a different language. Whether the second possibility is feasible depends, once again, on the environment: for instance on XULrunner you can make use of C libraries by wrapping them as XPCOM objects. In the browser you do not have this freedom

Answer (score 6):

Flash and Silverlight are both *platforms* and so have a known list of things the platform supports.

JavaScript is a language not a platform. The list of things it does and does not support, in terms of "working with file systems" or "web cam support" is really dictated by the platform on which you are running the language.

Most people, most of the time, run JavaScript in a web browser, so the list of what it supports is more about what the web browser will let you access with JavaScript.

Generally, this means unrestricted file access is not available (for security reasons). Web cams may be accessible depending on the browser and version.

But overall, I think you might need to re-think the question you are asking, because you may well really mean - "what can I and can't I do from within my web browser's environment". Failing that, you may mean, "what language features does JavaScript support" - in which case you should be able to find a number of descriptions of JavaScript as a language and comparisons to other languages.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript is initially the **programming language** that interacts with User Interface on a HTML document.

Javascript on DOM / HTML can:

- Apply, change, unset CSS styles of an element in the document
- Addition, modification, removal of document elements
- UI event handling (such as onclick, onchange, etc.)
- AJAX, JSON, etc.

After years of development and expansion, the language is now dependent on the platform's ability.

For example on Adobe AIR, Javascript's features can be as wide as an average C# application (meaning to say that you can write Javascript to read/write files, web cam, JSON parsing, socket etc.)

Basically my point is, Javascript is ultimately just a language. You can run the same language on multiple platforms, and the objects pre-defined by the platform is accessed by you as the developer using Javascript.

Comment: could you be more specific about "Axaj, Json, ect." Can javascript parse xml? can it parse pdf? can it decode and encode audio files?

Comment: If I were to write it that way, should I also include if Javascript can run tree structures, AI algorithms etc?

Comment: Your answer - is a question.. hmm... could you just list what 'formats' is avalible in javascript (for example: json, xml, pdf, txt, rtf)

Answer (score 1):

Flash and Silverlight are third party web browser plugins where javascript is built into most browsers (apart form some text based/disablity browsers). Javascript is a client side scripting language which means all the processing is done on your visitors computer.

I can tell you that you cannot work with file systems ie. create/edit/delete files on the server or the clients machine for obvious security reasons. You can parse JSON as it is javascript object notation. You can do form validation though its always best to have server side validation to ensure data quality. The reason you would do validation before the data is submitted is to save a run trip to the server and provide the user with instint feedback like you do with normal desktop applications. You can create charts using javascript and theres always loads of support and tutorials.

What specifically are you looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

Some things that Javascript can do:

- Handle events. It can catch certain event, (ex. pressing a key), and then execute a function (ex. change size of an element on page);
- Send requests to server thus interacting with server;
- Access and manipulate any element on page.

It is also object oriented programming language, thus it supports such concepts as class, inheritance, variables etc.

Some things that Javascript (in browser environment) cannot do:

- Work with databases;
- create, modify or remove files;

Comment: could you be more specific about second one, what king of requests javasctipt can send? can it establish soket connection? can it work with SOAP, REST and so one..

Comment: Javascript can handle events *in a browser environment*. So, what you can do with javascript depends on the environment it runs in. You *can* handle databases and files using javascript in node.js or wscript for example.

Comment: @Kooilnc plz read firs update, if it depends on platform, them list plaform and features for each platform

Comment: @Kooinlc - Thanks for reminding, I edited my answer

Comment: For example: if i send file in javascript as a string (i mean not byte array, but array of 'chars'), can i somehow parse this string to modify it. If so.. then it's mean i CAN work with files in JavaScript :)

Comment: For future readers: as of HTML 5, JavaScript gained a file writing API. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/